# Filters issue with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big little issue with the filters on Angular, to be explicit: input search with a filter attached.

[if you see this example, is exactly what I want](http://plnkr.co/edit/FJ45nV6gdwp3SkRglPeW?p=preview)

actually I did that Plnkr with the real information of my app. You can search through sports and his leagues, but in my app you can not, you can just search through the sports and once you try to search any leagues, the app returns a message **"did not match any search criteria"**, below I will put all of the code regarding this issue, someone says it could be a routing issue or that I am missing a resolve or something like that, that's why I am here, because I need your help. Also I recorded a [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdyjUy13os8&feature=youtu.be) for you to understand easier, as you see on the video if I put "college" the filter works, but below there are 2 leagues starting with "ncaa", if I type "ncaa" then the empty message shows up. It is weird because in the Plnkr example everything works properly.

**sportsList.html**

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Sports finder..."
       ng-model="query">


<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
     ng-if="sport.leagues.length">
     <!--this filter works correctly-->
        {{sport.name}}

      <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query">
      <!--this filter do not any respond-->
        {{league.name}}

  </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.sports', {
      url:'/sports',
      views:{
        menuContent:{
          templateUrl:'templates/sportsList.html',
          controller:'SportsController'
        }
      }
    })
```

**service.js**

```
  .factory('SportsFactory', function($http, $q, AuthFactory,
            LocalForageFactory, LeaguesFactory, CONSTANT_VARS) {
    return {
      getSports: function(agent) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)
          .then(function(sports) {
            if (!_.isNull(sports)) {
              defer.resolve(_.values(sports));
            }else {
              $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + agent)
                .success(function(sports) {
                  //forcing array instead of object
                  sports = _.values(sports);
                  sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
                    return sport.priority;
                  });
                  LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
                  defer.resolve(sports);
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                  defer.reject(err);
                });
            }
          });
        return defer.promise;
      },
      getSportsWithLeagues: function(customer) {
        var _this = this,
          defer = $q.defer(),
          rejection = function(err) {
            defer.reject(err);
          },
          sportsLength;

        LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_LEAGUES)
          .then(function(sportLeagues) {
            if (!_.isNull(sportLeagues)) {
              //forcing array instead of object

              sportLeagues = _.values(sportLeagues);
              defer.resolve(sportLeagues);
            }else {
              _this.getSports(customer.agent).then(function(sports) {
                sportsLength = sports.length;
                LeaguesFactory.getLeagues({
                  sportIds: _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
                  lineProfile: customer.lineProfile,
                  betLimit: customer.betLimit
                }).then(function(leagues) {
                  _.each(sports, function(sport) {
                    sport.leagues = _.filter(leagues, function(league) {
                      return sport.id === league.sport.id;
                    });
                  });
                  //forcing array instead of object
                  sports = _.values(sports);
                  LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_LEAGUES, sports);
                  defer.resolve(sports);
                }, rejection);
              }, rejection);
            }
          }, rejection);
        return defer.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, $state,
             AuthFactory, SportsFactory) {
    $scope.sports = [];
    $scope.customer = {};

    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (sports.length) {
          $scope.sports = sports;
        }else {
          AuthFactory.logout();
        }
      }, function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
      });
    }, function(err) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $state.go('app.login');
      console.log(err);
    });
```

what are your suggestions ?

Comment: Re-examine your assumptions about what is equivalent between the sample and the app. Reduce the app code (or build up the sample code) until you have hit the issue. It does not help at all to say that you have reduced the issue but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should to resolve the service in the route, here is an example:

```
views:{
    menuContent:{
      templateUrl:'templates/sportsList.html',
      controller:'SportsController',
      resolve: {
        Sports: function(sportsService, $q) {
          var defer = $q.defer();
          sportsService.getSports().then(function getAllSports(allSports) {
            defer.resolve(allArticles);
          });
          return defer.promise;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then just call Sports resolved in your controller

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, Sports) {
  $scope.sports = Sports
```

Somethig like that, this just an example, you should to call the AuthFactory in the resolve as well.

Here is the documentation for resolve:

[resolve documentation for ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

hope this help, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Auto answering just for future issues, the proper way to do it and avoiding anti patterns:

```
.state('app.sports', {
  url:'/sports',
  views:{
    menuContent:{
      templateUrl:'templates/sportsList.html',
      controller:'SportsController',
      resolve: {
        Customer: ['AuthFactory', function(AuthFactory) {
          return AuthFactory.getCustomer();
        }],
        Sports: ['SportsFactory', 'Customer', function(SportsFactory, Customer) {
          return SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(Customer);
        }],
        Leagues: ['Sports', 'LeaguesFactory', function(Sports, LeaguesFactory) {
          return LeaguesFactory.getLeagues(Sports);
        }]
      }
    }
  }
})
```